# Using DTDs to Parse XML

Tags: python, lxml, dtd, xml

I'm attempting to parse the USPTO data that is hosted [Here](http://www.google.com/googlebooks/uspto-patents-grants-text.html). I have also retrieved the DTDs associated with the files. My question is: is it possible to use these to parse the files, or are they only used for validation?  I have already used one as a guideline for parsing some of the documents, but doing it the way I am would require having a separate parser for each DTD. Here is an example snippet of how I'm currently doing it.

```
# <!ELEMENT document-id (country, doc-number, kind?, name?, date?)>
def parseDocumentId(ref):
  data = {}

  data["Country"] = ref.find("country").text
  data["ID"] = ref.find("doc-number").text

  if ref.find("date") != None:
    d= ref.find("date").text
    try:
        date = datetime.strptime(d, "%Y%m%d").date()
    except:
        date= None
    data["Date"]= date

  if ref.find("kind") != None:
    data["Kind"]= ref.find("kind").text

  if ref.find("name") != None:
    data["Name"]= ref.find("name").text


  return data
```

This way just seems very manual to me, so I'm curious if there is a better way to help automate the process

Note: I'm using lxml for parsing.

Comment: by parse, do you mean mapping the xml into an object (a DOM of some kind)?

Comment: My goal is to be able to extract pretty much all of the information in the files and store them in a DB. I currently have the data in tree form through the use of lxml.etree. I was hoping that there was a way to use the DTD's to guide me through the tree in order to extract the information

Answer (score 0):

DTDs will just help you to follow specifications. You can create a dictionary for tokenize the document and then parse it. Anyway, I believe that using lxml is the better way.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to processing XML is to use an off-the-shelf XML parser for your programming language, and from its API construct whatever data structures you want to have.  When many XML documents using the same XML vocabulary must be processed, it may make sense to generate a parser for that class of XML documents using a tool, or even to construct a parser by hand.  But most programs use generic XML parsers instead of custom-constructed parsers.

To store XML documents in a database, however, it may not be necessary to employ an XML parser at all (except perhaps in checking beforehand that the documents are all in fact well-formed):  all XML databases and many SQL databases have the ability to read and ingest XML documents.